# for loop and use the value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below line in XML.

```
<tb class="3">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>English words </b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>Arabic </b>
      </td>
      <td al="r">
        <b>Arabic</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bear </td>
      <td>ḍam</td>
      <td al="r">new</td>
    </tr>
</tb>
```

Here is my xslt.

```
<xsl:template name="table" match="tb">
    <table class="frame-all">
        <xsl:call-template name="cols"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="cols">
    <xsl:variable name="numbr" select="number(./@class)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="colcnt" select="format-number(100 div $numbr,'##.#')"/>
    <colgroup>
        <!-- I want the condition here-->
    </colgroup>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives me output of `33.3`. And I want to create 3 cols(the class attribute value). And for each `col` the name should be increment value. as below.

```
<col name="1" width="33.3"/>
<col name="2" width="33.3"/>
<col name="3" width="33.3"/>
```

please let me know, how can i get the above result.

Thanks

Comment: Please show a complete input XML document and a complete stylesheet that allow to reproduce your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, only this line is used to loop and create the expected output, this is actually a table with 3 rows, and based on this `class` value, i need to generate, the column widths.

Comment: Those lines alone are not an XSLT stylesheet. We do not see the template match, and we do not see the relevant input, for example the `cls` attribute. Please give complete information.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, sorry for my mistake, I've updated my question.

Comment: That's only half of what I asked for. Please also add enough of the XSLT code (a complete, minimal, working sample stylesheet). Variables do not lead to _any_ output in XSLT, so we don't know how and what output you are generating.

Comment: Updated it @MathiasMüller.

Comment: Still no `cls` attribute in the input, and still not a stylesheet that would enable us to reproduce the problem, and finally the output does not match the stylesheet snippet. I am inclined to give up.

Comment: Sorry for my multiple mistakes @MathiasMüller, I've updated my stylesheet for the final time.

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, can you please help me fix this. please.

Comment: I can't, even if I wanted to. We still do not have a complete input, a complete stylesheet and a complete expected output. In case I was not clear enough, _completeness_ is what matters here. For example, there is a `colgroup` element in your stylesheet, but it does not appear in the expected output.

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, I've solved it, below is my solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer.

```
<xsl:template name="table" match="tb">
        <table class="frame-all">
            <xsl:call-template name="cols"/>
            <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="colgroup">
        <xsl:param name="count" select="./@cls"/>
        <xsl:param name="final" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="colcnt" select="format-number(100 div number(./@cls),'##.#')"/>
        <col class="colnum-{$final} colname-col{$final} colwidth-{$colcnt}"></col>
        <xsl:if test="$final &lt; $count">
            <xsl:call-template name="colgroup">
                <xsl:with-param name="final" select="$final +1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="cols">
        <xsl:variable name="numbr" select="number(./@cls)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="colcnt" select="format-number(100 div $numbr,'##.#')"/>
        <colgroup>
            <xsl:call-template name="colgroup"/>
        </colgroup>
        <xsl:for-each select="tr">
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>       
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
<td>

<xsl:attribute name="align">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./@al='r'">
<xsl:text>right</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="./@al='c'">
<xsl:text>center</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>left</xsl:text>   
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:apply-templates/>
</td>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, then one way to generate a specific number of elements, in your case `col` elements, is to use a variation of the `xsl:for-each` to do a specific number of iterations.

So, instead of doing `<xsl:call-template name="colgroup"/>` to call a recursive template, you could do this:

```
<colgroup>
   <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer($numbr)">
      <col name="{.}" width="{$colcnt}"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</colgroup>
```

Note that you will need to define the `xs` namespace prefix in your stylesheet as follows

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
```